# ¿Es correcto crear una llave foránea que apunte a dos llaves primarias?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, diseño

Estoy diseñando una base de datos para un restaurante y una de las necesidades de diseño es poder crear menús.

Se pueden crear menús que contengan platos y menús para bebidas.

He pensado en un diseño de tablas, como el que se muestra en la imagen (Por simplicidad solo muestro las columnas mas relevantes de cada entidad), pero en dicho diseño me surge la duda, **¿Si la llave foránea `idProducto` de la tabla `detalleMenu` puede apuntar a dos tablas diferentes? ¿Cómo realizar la consulta de los menús existentes? ¿Esto se puede hacer?**

El motivo de la existencia de la tabla `detalleMenu` es, porque un plato puede estar en diferentes menús, al igual que la bebida podría estar en diferentes menús.

**¿Cuál es la forma mas ideal para resolver este problema?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se puede?, sí. Pero la verdad es que no hace sentido. Sería mucho mejor que uses las columnas `idPlato` e `idBebida` en `DetalleMenu` en vez de `idProducto` e `idTipoProducto`

Comment: Es mas tanto platos como bebidas son productos por lo que seguramente deberian ser una única tabla. Un menu tiene productos y los productos de sividen en categorias (platos, bebidas).

Comment: Umm yo se lo que quiere decir el joven con relacionar dos llaves primarias con una foranea, pongan el ejemplo de un sistema de ventas y uno de compras donde las llaves de pedido a clientes y pedido a proveedores necesiten llegar a una tabla kardex donde hay una llave que recibira a ambas llaves primarias

Answer (score 2):

Más que incorrecto, es poco práctico. Diseñar de ese modo la bbdd va a hacer que no puedas aprovechar las restricciones del SGBD sobre las claves foráneas dado que no podés saber de antemano cuál tabla tenés que restringir. Esto te puede llevar rápidamente a que se pierda la integridad de los datos al poder eliminar registros sin restricciones.

Deberías tener tablas que funcionen de nexo entre el menú y los productos que lo componen.

[image: Diagrama BBDD]

De esta forma podés establecer fácilmente las claves foráneas, evitás los campos con null y no tenés que alterar la estructura de la tabla si sacás o agregás algún nuevo tipo de producto en el menú.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias tenes dos campos en la tabla DetalleMenu: 
idPlato 
idBebida
cada uno con su clave foranea.

El motivo es sencillo, se podria dar el caso en que el idPlato y el IdBebida sean iguales... eso causaria duplicidad o algún otro problema.

Obviamente los dos campos deben permitir nulos, si quieres validar que nunca te dejen los 2 campos como nulos usa un Constraint para validar eso.

Comment: en efecto, este tipo de union se llama M:M que significa muchos a muchos o many to many, aunque yo preferiria hacer que las dos llaves foraneas se convirtieran en la llave primaria de la nueva tabla

Comment: Te refieres a dos columnas además de `idMenu`, cierto?

Comment: Entonces suponiendo que exista el menu id=1 , y id=2 donde id=1 es para un menu de bebidas y id=2 es para un menu de platos, al momento de realizar una consulta para el menu 1, todos los campos de la columna idBebida serian null, al igual que al hacer una consulta para el menu 2 los campos de la columna idPlato serian null?. Y si por ejemplo quiciera un menu de postres, tambien tendria que agregar otra columna llamada idPostre en la tabla detalleMenu?

Answer (score 0):

En términos de Normalización sería mas "correcto" que platos y bebidas compartan una misma tabla (productos) y se diferencien entre si por `tipoProducto`.
 `DetalleMenu` sería el nexo entre `menus` y `productos` (`idMenu`, `idProducto`) con algún detalle extra de la relación por ejemplo:

```
[menu]
idMenu: 1
menuNombre: Pisco Pollo Fantástico
menuOferta: incluye pisco gratis y 50% descuento en zanahorias hervidas
```

---

```
[MenuDetalle]
idMenu: 1
idProducto: 1
descuento: 0

idMenu: 1
idProducto: 3
descuento: 100%

idMenu: 1
idProducto: 2
descuento: 50%
```

---

```
[productos]
idProducto : 1
productoNombre : Pollo grillado
idProductoTipo : 1

idProducto : 2
productoNombre : Zanahoria hervida
idProductoTipo : 2

idProducto : 3
productoNombre : pisco sour
idProductoTipo : 3
```

---

```
[productoTipos]
idProductoTipo : 1
productoTipo: Plato Caliente

idProductoTipo : 2
productoTipo: Plato Frio

idProductoTipo : 3
productoTipo: Bebida con alcohol

idProductoTipo : 4
productoTipo: Postre
```

La cantidad de campos extra en `MenuDetalle` dependerá de cómo sea el asunto final.

Answer (score 0):

Está correcto eso de usar bebidas y platos como productos genéricos
Pero quizás nuestro amigo necesita guardar datos específicos para cada uno
Especificar datos explícitos. Yo también estoy pensando en algo similar
En cosas que son "similares", pero con estructuras diferentes
Onda, en el caso del amigo: son 2 tablas
Yo deseo conjugar 3 tablas.

Mi idea es una tabla principal donde se genere un id automático (porque necesito un contador)
Las tablas entidad explícitas (el amigo tiene 2, yo tendría 3)
Y al final. Una tabla de relación múltiple que conjugue la tabla principal que genera el ID automático, con las 3 tablas entidad especificas

---

Mi error.
El amigo [Roberto Vaccaro] de más arriba tiene razón
1 tabla menú, 2 tablas relacionadoras menu_bebidas y menu_platos, y 2 tablas platos y bedidas
También me serviría
1 tabla OrdenTrabajo, 3 tablas OrdenTrabajo[Receta] y 3 tablas [Receta]
Hasta he pensando en manera para comprobar si hay de un tipo, otro, diversos o todos los tipos de [Receta] para utilizar consultas para extraer datos de manera explícita